# Upgrading Cassandra from 3.0.14 to 3.11.2

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I had 4 nodes on 3.0.14 and I had to upgrade 2 of them to 3.11.2 and decommission the other 2. First I decommissioned the 2 nodes, one-by-one. After that I stopped cassandra 3.0.14 on the other 2 nodes and installed the 3.11.2 version alternately. However, in the system logs of both the nodes, I see the following:

> INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2018-03-12 16:28:50,621 Gossiper.java:1193 -
>   There is at least one 3.0 node in the cluster - will store and
>   announce compatible schema version

I don't understand why it's saying that still there is one 3.0 node when the only 2 nodes that I have in my cluster are now running 3.11.2.

I also used the following command on both the nodes to check the version

> nodetool version

the command returned "ReleaseVersion: 3.11.2" in both the cases.

PS: I've added cassandra-3.0 as a tag for this questions as I couldn't find cassandra-3.1.

Comment: do you know all node in the same cluster must have the same version!

Comment: and all nodes in the cluster are having the same version. I don't understand why are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an INFO message, it doesn't mean anything is wrong. All Cassandra nodes keep information about each other, such as token ranges, IP, version, etc. Since you stopped both Cassandra nodes at the same time that means they both think the other node is still on Cassandra 3.0 until they learn otherwise.

So what happens is that when you start a node with 3.11 it will first update this information about itself. It will notice that itself has been updated to 3.11 but there are other nodes with 3.0 in the cluster. Now it will send this information on to all other nodes notifying them that itself has been updated to 3.11.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't stopped both the nodes at the same time. First, I stopped only one of them, upgraded it, turned it on and then stopped the other node and did the same thing.

Comment: Well, then it's even more obvious why you get the message. I would assume you get this on only the first node you upgraded.

Comment: I remember it was observed in both nodes. I'll recheck and let you know.

Comment: I checked and the statement "There is at least one 3.0 node in the cluster - will store and announce compatible schema version" shows up in the system logs of both nodes!

Comment: @VishalSharma That seems very strange. And you did decommission before upgrading these nodes? Are there any other nodes left in the cluster? Can you do a SELECT * on system.peers to make sure.

Comment: Yes I had decommissioned the nodes before upgrading the other nodes. I see only 2 nodes when I use nodetool status command. I see the info of only 1 node when I use the select statement given by you(the node on which I run cql).

Comment: Well, then I can't explain it because it seems impossible to happen. Just ignore it and move on since you checked that there are no longer any 3.0 nodes in the cluster.

Comment: It's alright. But I didn't understand your method of checking all the existing nodes in the cluster. I generally use nodetool status. I used the select statement provided by you above, on system.peers, but that statement just provided the info of the node on which I was running cql.

Comment: @VishalSharma That select statement should show information about all other nodes, not itself. It saves information about itself in system.local. I wanted you to look in the system.peers table to check what version the other node has. I hope that makes sense.